# Android - How to click through transparent area of custom view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

In order to position a button in the exact spot on all devices, I have created it with a custom view. The button takes up a small part of the screen but the actual view takes up most of the screen. All the area around the button is transparent. How can I allow the user to click through the transparent area to buttons underneath but still click the button area on the view?

Here is the relavant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final float dotScale = 0.3f;
Dot dot1, dot2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
MyView myView = new MyView(this);
myLayout.addView(myView);

// Two dots are created.

dot1 = new Dot(this);
dot1.xOffset = 2.9f;
dot1.yOffset = 3.3f;
myLayout.addView(dot1);
dot2 = new Dot(this);
dot2.xOffset = -2.4f;
dot2.yOffset = 1.1f;
myLayout.addView(dot2);

// Makes dots clickable

dot1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!dot1.isClicked) {
            dot1.animate().setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator())
                    .scaleXBy(dotScale).scaleYBy(dotScale).alpha(1.0f);
            dot1.isClicked = true;
        }
    }
});

dot2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!dot2.isClicked) {
            dot2.animate().setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator())
                    .scaleXBy(dotScale).scaleYBy(dotScale).alpha(1.0f);
            dot2.isClicked = true;
        }
    }
});

}

.......

//custom view for Dots

class Dot extends View {

int radius;
float xOffset;
float yOffset;
boolean isClicked = false;

public Dot(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setClickable(true);


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int x = getWidth();
    int y = getHeight();
    double ratio = (547d / 828d);
    float circleX = (float)((x / 2) - (y * ratio) / xOffset);
    float circleY = (float)(y / yOffset);

    radius = (int)((float)y/13);
    setPivotX(circleX);
    setPivotY(circleY);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, paint);
}


}
```

Comment: Please enrich your question with some code, it's hardly possible to give you a precise answer

Comment: Code added to question.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your view `clickable` and don't override `onTouch` at all or just return `false` from it. Return `false` means that you didn't consume event and it will be forwarded to the next element in view hierarchy.

Comment: I have been trying onTouch. However, I do not think there is a hierarchy to my views so doing this does not make the view underneath get clicked.

Comment: @BeauCarnes, is your view with button (`MyView?`) matching parent for some purpose? If not, add view with `myLayout.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`. It will set `wrap_content` and view will be size of content